# adding a folder to a repository

Tags: git, github

How can I add a folder to a repository in github (by commands) that has been created before?

I have a repository in github that i have created before now i want to add it to a folder in my PC by commands.
git clone and git init but dont know how to mention the specific repositories name.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Use

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

This will bring the repo to your local device
Then,
`git rm unwanted-file.txt`
Then commit and push your local to the repo.
Remember to use Deletion command after cloning to local.